# Trigger is updating multiples rows with the same value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

The trigger is updating multiple rows with the same value

Here a problem, I'm trying to update one or many rows in a table(B), but its updating the rows with the same value let's say

TABLE A

```
+------+-----+-----+
|ROWID |NAME |CODE |
+------+-----+-----+
| 123  |pepe |  1  |
| 456  |tito |  2  |
| 789  |gege |  3  |
-------------------
```

Current result:

```
+------+-----+-----+---------+
|ROWID |NAME |CODE | A_ROWID |
+------+-----+-----+---------+
| 321  |rolo |  1  |  123    |
| 654  |kit  |  2  |  123    |
| 987  |gu   |  3  |  123    |
-----------------------------
```

Expected result:

```
+------+-----+-----+---------+
|ROWID |NAME |CODE | A_ROWID |
+------+-----+-----+---------+
| 321  |rolo |  1  |  123    |
| 654  |kit  |  2  |  456    |
| 987  |gu   |  3  |  789    |
-----------------------------
```

This is the trigger, I will really appreciate any advice

```sql
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRIG_AfterInsert] 
ON [dbo].[B] 
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Code nvarchar(100);

    SELECT @Code = CODE FROM INSERTED;

    UPDATE B 
    SET B.A_ROWID = A.ROWID 
    FROM A 
    WHERE A.CODE = @Code;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger is called once per the statement, which means if you are updating one row it will be called once, if you are updating 1 million rows it will be called once again.

So, now when you know triggers core behavior you should refactor these lines below:

```sql
declare @Code nvarchar(100);
select @Code=CODE from INSERTED;
```

So, full trigger code will be:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo.TRIG_AfterInsert ON dbo.B AFTER INSERT AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE B
    SET B.A_ROWID = A.ROWID 
    FROM B 
         JOIN INSERTED I ON I.ROWID = B.ROWID
         JOIN A ON A.CODE = I.CODE;
END
```

Just take a look there is `inserted` table directly in the join, and with this statement you will filter all the rows you need.

Where clause in your statement is converted in the `JOIN`.